# Python: how to detect duplicates in a list to signal a different operation

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a large table of data that I have split into individual lists, for example:(lists virticle)

```
A=[1,1,2,2,3,3,3]
B=[6,3,5,3,8,4,3]
```

What I would like to achieve is 2 new lists where list A is condensed down into non-repeating values and where a repeated value occurs in A the new corrosponding value of B is the addition of its elements corresponding to that value, for example I would like the two new lists to be:

```
C=[1,2,3]
D=[9,8,15]
```

I would like to extend this over a much larger amount of data in the lists, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby),

```
import itertools
import operator
import collections

A=[1,1,2,2,3,3,3] 
B=[6,3,5,3,8,4,3]

d = collections.OrderedDict()

for key, group in itertools.groupby(zip(A, B), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    d[key] = sum(map(operator.itemgetter(1), group))


C = d.keys()        # [1, 2, 3]
D = d.values()      # [9, 8, 15]
```

---

In one line using list comprehensions,

```
d = collections.OrderedDict({key : sum(map(operator.itemgetter(1), group)) 
                            for key, group in itertools.groupby(zip(A, B), key=operator.itemgetter(0))})
```

Comment: Should this method still hold when using numbers in the form 2.10E-07? I find that it doesn't add together these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to add the values. Then make 2 lists from that dictionary. One from the keys and another from the values.

```
A = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3] 
B = [6,3,5,3,8,4,3]

Concate = dict()

for i in range(len(A)):

    if(A[i] in Concate):
        Concate[A[i]]+=B[i]
    else:
        Concate.update({A[i]:B[i]})

C = list(Concate.keys())
D = list(Concate.values())
print("C=",C)
print("D=",D)
```

Comment: Should this method still hold when using numbers in the form 2.10E-07? I find that it doesn't add together these numbers?

Comment: @L.hue no. If the numbers are in that format then it won't work. But if it's like 0.0000001 then it will work.

Comment: My list B fully contains numbers in this form, is it possible to modify the code to get the correct outputs?

Comment: @L.hue SHould be.

Comment: @L.hue or you can change the format first after reading it from file then process it.

Comment: How would convert my entire list into the decimal form?

Comment: is it in a text file ?? @L.hue

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to find a way. If i find, i will let you know. @L.hue

Comment: @L.hue You just need to erase the space if there is any space between 10E and - or - and 07.

Comment: When I use my data the first out put of list D is '2.10410E-072.30556E-091.38068E-11'

Comment: @L.hue It's because of huge precision. 2.1E-72 !! You can't print 72 digits after decimal point. So, you have to output in that format. and It's not wrong output.

Comment: A=[1,1] B=[5.41031E-08, 3.82965E-12 ] here is the first values so the output shoud be C=[1] and D=[5.41069e-8], my values aren't precise to 72 digits.

Comment: @L.hue It's giving correct output here. Output - C= [1] and D= [5.410692965e-08]

Comment: I presume there must be an error somewhere else in my code because once I set A and B to equal my data lists it gives the very strange outputs for D

Comment: By the way, A and B lists must have equal length.  @L.hue

Comment: Yes, my data lists do have the same length.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, perhaps this is a more simpler way of doing it. I just used some for loops and stuffs.

```
a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3]
b = [6,3,5,3,8,4,3]
c = []
d = []
dValue = 0 #Used for keeping track of what goes in d array

for index in range(len(a)):
    try:
       c.index(a[index])    #See if program has already checked a duplicate value
    except:                 #If not checked, do the following; If has checked, do nothing
        c.append(a[index])   #Place value in c array
        for sameNumbers in range(len(a)):    #Here checking for duplicate values
            if a[sameNumbers] == a[index]:
                dValue += b[sameNumbers]    #dValue increases by the corresponding b index
        d.append(dValue)     #Put dValue in array
        dValue = 0           #Reset dValue for next time

print(c, d) #[1, 2, 3],[9, 8, 15]
```